# WFS GetFeature with multiple layers and different propertyNames

Tags: maps, geoserver

Suppose i have a Geoserver running with two layers exposed by WFS (with properties):

```
StreetLayer (geom, StreetName, Lanes, Length)
HouseLayer (geom, Address)
```

Now if i want to query StreetLayer for all streets but only get the StreetName and Lanes properties I'd send a GET request to this:

```
http://geoserver/wfs?REQUEST=GetFeature&VERSION=1.1.0&typename=StreetLayer&propertyname=StreetName,Lanes
```

But what if i now want to query both HouseLayer and StreetLayer? This doesn't work:

```
http://geoserver/wfs?REQUEST=GetFeature&VERSION=1.1.0&typename=StreetLayer,HouseLayer&propertyname=StreetName,Lanes,Address
```

I get an exception that says that StreetName and Lanes isn't in HouseLayer and vice versa. Do i need to make multiple requests?

**EDIT:**

So what i want to do is something like this:

```
http://geoserver/wfs?REQUEST=GetFeature&VERSION=1.1.0&typename=StreetLayer,HouseLayer&propertyname=(StreetName,Lanes),(Address)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Almost there, you just have an extra comma in propertyName. This one works against the vanilla GeoServer install:

```
http://localhost:8087/gswps/topp/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=topp:tasmania_cities,topp:tasmania_roads&propertyName=(ADMIN_NAME,CITY_NAME)(TYPE)
```

The difference: No comma between ) and (

Comment: If I add outputFormat=json I get a list of features without reference to their typename. Is there a way to get an according typename for a feature in this case?

Comment: As I answered on the GeoServer users mailing list, nope, it's a limitation of the GeoJSON format, it does not have a notion of a layer.